# Date picker issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento, calendar

I am going through a strange issue in my Magento module.

- I cant select dates in magento datepicker (calendar) if the present
  date is disabled.
- But, If I click any of the date in present month and go to the next
  month and comes back, then I can select the dates!!!!!!

My code below,

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField : '_dob',
        ifFormat : '%d/%m/%y',
        button : '_dob_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
        date: '25/6/2013',
```

Here by date attribute, I am trying to set a default date. But it too doesnt work. If I enables the present date to selectable, then the calendar works perfectly!

If anyone went through this before please share your solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got a solution...!

There is a `calendar.j`s file in magento's default `js` folder. In that, there is a `currentDateEl` parameter. I changed it to `currentDateEl: 25/06/2013`... The issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the wrong format for the default date, it needs to be an integer YYYYMMDD.

Have you tried using the `min: 20130625` variable in stead of an adjusted default date?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure work or not. If not work, you may be edit a little bit in this code.

```
        Calendar.setup({
        inputField : '_dob',
        ifFormat : '%d/%m/%y',
        button : '_dob_trig',
        align : 'Bl',
        singleClick : true,
        disableFunc: function(date) {
              var today = new Date();
              var dd = today.getDate();
              var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

              var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
              if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
              return today;
        }
 });
```